# How to select item in group list in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a collection of item on a web page and all items have the same class. The elements do not have IDs. When I use class name, it will pick only the first item, but I want click on the second item. How can i click .

My code :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("item-group-list"));
element.click();
```

Comment: Relevant HTML and code trials and error stack trace (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use findElements method to get all elements then click on second item as given below.

```
List<WebElement> lstElements = driver.findElements(By.className("item-group-list"));
lstElements.get(1).click();
```

or You can try with x-path `(//*[@class='item-group-list'])[2]` to get the second element directly as follows.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='item-group-list'])[2]")); //index starts with 1 here
   element.click();
```